# restrict html5 video display per session?

Tags: php, wordpress, video, html5-video, jwplayer

I want to restrict video and photo displays per session. For example, visitor watches 3 videos and when he tries to watch a fourth video he's redirected to a subscription page. I'll be using JWPlayer or native HTML5, doesn't matter, and this would work in WP, but looking to any way to do it with PHP (I'm not an expert by any mean).

So, ideally, this would be teh workflow:
    1)visitor watches video1 --> optional message --> you have 2 videos left
    2)visitor watches video2 --> optional message --> you have 1 videos left
    3)visitor watches video3 --> optional message --> you have 0 videos left
    4)visitor tries to watch video4 --> redirect

So far I found ways to limit per bandwidth or per time (only 1 video and then redirect), but I need to serve exactly 3 videos, no matter the time or size, so those solutions won't work. Any idea on how to achieve this?

edit: here's some code to redirect, I really didn't add anything yet because nothing is what I need, but take a look:

```
<script src="text/javascript">
function vidplay(){
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    video.play();
    video.addEventListener('ended',function(){
        window.location = 'http://SUBSCRIBE_PAGE';
    });
}
</script>
<video controls id="video" width="640" height="360" onclick="vidplay()">
    <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: What if the user clears their session?

Comment: Please add any code you've already tried to solve your problem.

Comment: yes, that's an issue, the best way would be to restrict per IP per 24 hours limit or so, but at this point I'd be happy with anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store a count in the Session (ideally a list of video ID's so they can watch the same video multiple times in the one session), this may be nullified by the user clearing cookies. Otherwise, if your users have an account they must log into, store a history of what they've watched against a database table.

Edit: Now I noticed you're using wordpress here, so I cant' help with adding it to that, but here's an example of a session based approeach

```
<?php

// Obviously use your variable here
$ID_OF_VIDEO_HERE = $_REQUEST['video'];

if(isset($_SESSION) === false)
  session_start(); // Start PHP session management
if(isset($_SESSION['videos_viewed']) === false)
  $_SESSION['videos_viewed'] = array();

if(isset($_SESSION['videos_viewed'][$ID_OF_VIDEO_HERE]) === FALSE AND count($_SESSION['videos_viewed']) >= 3)
{
  // Redirect the User
  header('location: http://SUBSCRIBE_PAGE');
  exit();
}
else
{
  // Add current video ID to list
  $_SESSION['videos_viewed'][$ID_OF_VIDEO_HERE] = true;
}

// JUST FOR TESTING
var_dump($_SESSION['videos_viewed']);

?>
```

Comment: You run into a few problems really, the users IP might be dynamic, they might be behind NAT, clearing cookies, changing user agents (probably not this so much). Also as a session may only last a short amount of time, you could also generate a unique ID and store that in a cookie as form of user identification for when after the session has ended, and use that to restrict. obviously users can clear cookies if they savvy enough, but you'll probably stop most people.

Comment: well, this is way over my limited skills, will try to find someone capable to do it. If you think yo can do it and there's a way to hire you, just lmk, I'm not sure as to what is the protocol for paid jobs here

Comment: thank you Scuzzy, I tried it in a single page and worked fine, working in adding it to WP, many thanx!  I can give you a vote up yet, but if I could, I would :)

Comment: Also, ensure the redirect only happens in the code to view a video, and not on every page, oh and an accepted answer is better anyway :)